# CakePHP using transactions (getDataSource) in Test Cases

Tags: unit-testing, cakephp, testing

In CakePHP 2.2.5 have a component that handles payments for my app. I can successfully run the function "addPayment" within the component from the browser/regular session but it fails when I run it in a test case.

I get the error "Trying to get property of non-object" when initializing a transaction with `$this->controller->Product->getDataSource();` within the component.

It seems like `$this->controller` or `$this->controller->Product` isn't being set in the component. Any ideas how I can fix it so that `$this->controller->Product->getDataSource();` works?

**app/Test/Case/Controller/Compnent/FinanceComponent:**

```
App::uses('ComponentCollection', 'Controller');
App::uses('Component', 'Controller');
App::uses('FinanceComponent', 'Controller/Component');

class TestFinanceController extends Controller {
    public $uses = array('Product');
}

class FinanceComponentTest extends CakeTestCase {

    public $Finance = null;
    public $Controller = null;

/**
 * setUp method
 *
 * @return void
 */
    public function setUp() {
        parent::setUp();

        $CakeRequest = new CakeRequest();
        $CakeResponse = new CakeResponse();
        $this->Controller = new TestFinanceController($CakeRequest, $CakeResponse);

        $Collection = new ComponentCollection();
        $this->Finance = new FinanceComponent($Collection);
        $this->Finance->startup($this->Controller);
    }

/**
 * tearDown method
 *
 * @return void
 */
    public function tearDown() {
        unset($this->Finance);
        unset($this->Controller);

        parent::tearDown();
    }

/**
 * testAddPayment method
 *
 * @return void
 */
    public function testAddPayment() {
        // Get products
        $products = $this->Controller->Product->find('all', array(
            'limit' => 2,
            'offset' => rand(2,6)
        ));
        $this->assertEquals(2, count($products));

    // hidden code to shorten example...

        // Test buying from main store
        $values = array(
            // hidden code to shorten example...
        );

        $payment = call_user_func_array(array($this->Finance, 'addPayment'), array_values($values));
    }
}
```

**app/Controller/Components/FinanceComponent.php:**

```
class FinanceComponent extends Component {

    /**
     * Controller instance reference
     *
     * @var object
     */
    public $controller;
    public $dataSource;

    public $mainUserId = 1;
    public $mainStoreId = 1;

    /**
     * Constructor
     */
    public function __construct(ComponentCollection $collection, $settings = array()) {
        parent::__construct($collection, $settings);
        $this->controller = $collection->getController();
    }

    public function addPayment($amount, $amountTax, $userId, $products, $storeId, $transactionId = null, $affiliateUserId = null) {
        // Start Transaction
        $this->__transactionStart();

        try {
                 // hidden code to shorten example...

            // Commit Transaction
            $this->__transactionCommit();

            return array(
                'status' => 'success'
            );

        } catch (Exception $e) {
            // Rollback Transaction
            $this->__transactionRollback();

            return array(
                'status' => 'error',
                'message' => 'Error ' . $e->getLine() . ': ' . $e->getMessage()
            );
        }
    }

    protected function __transactionStart() {
        $this->dataSource = $this->controller->Product->getDataSource();
        $this->dataSource->begin();
    }

    protected function __transactionRollback() {
        $this->dataSource->rollback();
    }

    protected function __transactionCommit() {
        $this->dataSource->commit();
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

CakePHP 2.x is using 'lazy loading' for a lot of things, it may be possible that the Model is not loaded because of that:

http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/appendices/2-0-migration-guide.html#models

It may be worth to have a look at the CakePHP test cases for the PaginatorComponent and look for examples:

https://github.com/cakephp/cakephp/blob/2.2.5/lib/Cake/Test/Case/Controller/Component/PaginatorComponentTest.php#L334

Probably, you'll need to manually call `Controller::constructClasses();` in order to properly initialise the components and models.